# Mysql - Unable to enable remote access

Tags: mysql, remote-access

I'm having trouble logging in remotely to mysql.

I've set up a user (open_user) without a password and I want to be able to connect with it to my db (open_db) from any remote server (yes I know its a security nightmare but I'm testing something out).
I can log in successfully from the local server:
***mysql -openuser open_db***

And when I view the grants for this user:
***show grants for openuser***
- I get this:

**GRANT USAGE ON *.*  TO 'openuser'@'%'**

**GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `open_db`.* TO 'openuser'@'%'**

My understanding is that this user should be able to log in from any server.

However when I try this:
***mysql -uopenuser -hmyserver open_db***

I get this:

**ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'openuser'@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' (using password: NO)**

I've also tried setting bind-address in /etc/mysql/my.cnf:

bind-address            = 0.0.0.0

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps

- Open Database Users for MySQL
- Edit your user(openuser)
- Write to Host **%**

This will give permission for all IP address for your user.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this,

```
mysql -h host -u username -p password
```